# Add a Key & Value in a HashMap from a different Class

Tags: java, class, dictionary, hashmap

I created a hashmap class with its constructor, getter and setter. I need to add a key and value in the hashmap from a different class and print the hashmap in the Main class.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Map {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hmap;
    public Map() {
        hmap= new HashMap<>();
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getMap()
    {
        return hmap;
    }
    public void setMap(String s, Integer i)
    {
        hmap.put(s,i);
    }
}

public class AddValue {
    public void add(){
        new Map().setMap("a",1);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AddValue().add();
        System.out.println(new Map().getMap());
    }
}
```

The Hashmap still shows empty when I add a value in a different class. How can I add the key & value in this HashMap in a different class and print it in the Main class?

Comment: Class Name must start with a capital letter as per the java code convention.[coding  convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html#:~:text=Interface%20names%20should%20be%20capitalized%20like%20class%20names.&text=Methods%20should%20be%20verbs%2C%20in,of%20each%20internal%20word%20capitalized.&text=Except%20for%20variables%2C%20all%20instance,with%20a%20lowercase%20first%20letter.)

Answer (score 1):

`new Map().getMap()`creates a new map. Hence its empty.

You have to store the map somewhere.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", 1);
        System.out.println(map.get("a"));
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** pass map to different class

You have to keep track of the map somehow. So you can pass the Map to a different class if needed. But is has to be the same Object.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapWrapper wrapper = new MapWrapper();
        Adder adder = new Adder(wrapper);
        adder.add();

        System.out.println(wrapper.getHmap().get("a"));
    }

    public static class Adder {
        private final MapWrapper wrapper;

        public Adder(MapWrapper wrapper) {
            this.wrapper = wrapper;
        }

        public void add() {
            wrapper.getHmap().put("a", 1);
        }
    }

    public static class MapWrapper {
        private final Map<String, Integer> hmap;

        public MapWrapper() {
            hmap = new HashMap<>();
        }

        public Map<String, Integer> getHmap() {
            return hmap;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** simplified version without wrapper:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        Adder adder = new Adder(map);
        adder.add();

        System.out.println(map.get("a"));
    }

    public static class Adder {
        private final Map<String, Integer> map;

        public Adder(Map<String, Integer> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        public void add() {
            map.put("a", 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: map.put("a",1) has to be done in a different class. How can I do that?